# Is it a good programming practice to separate models from the rest of the application

Tags: python, database, django, model

My project consists of several django applications that need to be deployed differently, possibly on different machines. However often these apps occasionally need to access each other's models, so I was thinking of "externalizing" my models so that they can be accessed more elegantly from any app. So the idea is to do have directory structure resembling something like this:

```
/ 
+ application1
+ application2
+ models
```

Is there a functional point to doing that (other than code maintainability), since the applications can cross-reference each other?

Comment: hard to say. can you think of a down side? would it get confusing with all of the models intermixed in one folder?

Comment: @dqhendricks: No, not really. In fact it would probably get easier to manage since we would have a single focus point for database interface...

Comment: Models **within apps** can depend on each other just fine.  Why try to extract the models?  What is "more elegantly"?  `from app.models import This, That` seems pretty elegant.  How could you improve on this?

Comment: @S.Lott: That's true. It just seems like there is some fragmentation happening, with apps having their own models that are describing only parts of the database schema.

Comment: @Goro: Fragmentation?  We call those "subject areas" and use them to break a complex problem down into smaller, related, simpler problems.  What's wrong with decomposing a big problem into smaller problems?

Comment: @S.Lott: I'm trying to find the best solution. I never said there was something wrong with it :) But what about a situation when the schema is strewn across many projects that have to be deployed differently (maybe on separate servers) - wouldn't it be easier to do database schema changes if all model code was in one place?

Comment: @Goro: "wouldn't it be easier to do database schema changes if all model code was in one place?"  Not necessarily.  If you've got databases on multiple servers, you've created considerable complexity of relatively low value.  Multiple "projects" is different from multiple Django applications within a single project.  The descriptions in the comments are a bit to abstract to visualize.  Feel free to **update** the question with more specifics on your situation.  Generalizations aren't worth much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following paragraph in the [django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter05/#cn82) makes me think that that's probably not a good idea (I added the bold formatting):

> However, there’s one requirement regarding the app convention: if you’re using Django’s database layer (models), you must create a Django app. **Models must live within apps**. Thus, in order to start writing our models, we’ll need to create a new app.

Comment: How do you infer from the quote that models need to live in _the same_ app in which they are used? Couldn't there just be a models app?

Comment: The letter of the law is sometimes different from the spirit behind it.  There could be a models app with a models model that had all the models in it.  The point is to avoid the monolithic monster app that has everything in it.  But.  You could, certainly, have one app with all the models and all the other apps are just collections of view functions.  But that's not the *spirit* of Django.

Answer (score 3):

The following didn't fit well in the comments to @jcollado's answer so I'll put it here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#models-across-files

> Models across files
>
> It's perfectly OK to relate a model to one from another app. To do this, import the related model at the top of the model that holds your model. Then, just refer to the other model class wherever needed. For example:

```
from geography.models import ZipCode

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    # ...
    zip_code = models.ForeignKey(ZipCode)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a particularly good idea, though I can see the appeal. You will be including a lot of models you're not using if you only want one of your apps installed. I think it's best to keep models within the app they most relate to.

This also may make using the admin interface more confusing. Where do you register the models with the admin? Where do you do the admin customization for a model?

Comment: Good point, but I think if it's done properly, it would make things tidier: If we move all the models to their own app, then we can just have the admin on _that_ app, encompassing all of the models.